# how can I dynamically set text in Textview in augmented reality application on the android studio

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

I want to make an android application that has "augmented reality" functionality in an android application like start the camera and show text virtually in real time. Please give me a suggestion about it.

```
Textview textview = (Textview) renderable.getView();
textview.setText("text");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, I think this should be the solution what you asking for...
You can write something like this:

```
if(textview.getText.equals("Turn on camera")){
    turnOnCamera();
}
else if (textview.getText.equals("Do something else")){
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

But you have to write each method for each action you want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the frame is added to the camera and progmatically add it in the OnResume() method :

```
 @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // ARCore requires camera permissions to operate. If we did not yet obtain runtime
    // permission on Android M and above, now is a good time to ask the user for it.
    if (!CameraPermissionHelper.hasCameraPermission(this)) {
      CameraPermissionHelper.requestCameraPermission(this);
      return;
    }

    JniInterface.onResume(nativeApplication, getApplicationContext(), this);
    surfaceView.onResume();

    // Update the radio buttons with the resolution info.
    String lowResLabel = JniInterface.getCameraConfigLabel(nativeApplication, true);
    String highResLabel = JniInterface.getCameraConfigLabel(nativeApplication, false);
    RadioButton lowResolutionRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_low_res);
    RadioButton highResolutionRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio_high_res);
    if (!lowResLabel.isEmpty()) {
      lowResolutionRadioButton.setText(lowResLabel);
    } else {
      lowResolutionRadioButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    if (!highResLabel.isEmpty()) {
      highResolutionRadioButton.setText(highResLabel);
    } else {
      highResolutionRadioButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```